# Disable CSS scroll snap after certain point

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap

OK so I have 7 sections, first 4 sections are CMYK, and last 3 sections are RGB.

I am trying to stop scroll snapping on sections RGB.

If I apply `scroll-snap-align: start;` to CMYK sections, when I scroll to end of section `.bg-key` (black) it always forces me to snap back to start of `.bg-key` (black) as I try to scroll down...

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.bg-cyan {
  background: cyan;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-magenta {
  background: magenta;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-key {
  background: black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main>
  <section class="bg-cyan">CYAN</section>
  <section class="bg-magenta">MAGENTA</section>
  <section class="bg-yellow">YELLOW</section>
  <section class="bg-key">BLACK</section>
  <section class="bg-red">RED</section>
  <section class="bg-blue">BLUE</section>
  <section class="bg-green">GREEN</section>
</main>
```

See fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/qday0r9o/4/

If I try using `scroll-snap-type: none;` on `.bg-red` section using tilde asterisk to get all elements after `.bg-red`, nothing happens? Every section still snaps? See here...

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  color: white;
}

/* Disable scroll snapping after .bg-red section */
section.bg-red ~ * {
  scroll-snap-type: none;
}

.bg-cyan {
  background: cyan;
}

.bg-magenta {
  background: magenta;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.bg-key {
  background: black;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main>
  <section class="bg-cyan">CYAN</section>
  <section class="bg-magenta">MAGENTA</section>
  <section class="bg-yellow">YELLOW</section>
  <section class="bg-key">BLACK</section>
  <section class="bg-red">RED</section>
  <section class="bg-blue">BLUE</section>
  <section class="bg-green">GREEN</section>
</main>
```

See fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/mbey5p6s/38/

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here...?

Would love to be able to disable css snapping after a certain point if possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @joshmoto, There is a solution for this but it works only on Firefox, https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-snap-stop/

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob this is how stack overflow code editor adds in external css libraries

Comment: Someone needs to fix that when even the W3C Validator will flag that.

Comment: @Rob you are right, had to see for myself. It is only an info flag but still a flag none the less... [https://i.imgur.com/RMywqci.png](https://i.imgur.com/RMywqci.png)

Answer (score 1):

When I change the "scroll-snap-type" to "both" on the html element, in your first example the black section does not snap back.
But as it is, the usability is poor.

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: both;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.bg-cyan {
  background: cyan;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-magenta {
  background: magenta;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-key {
  background: black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main>
  <section class="bg-cyan">CYAN</section>
  <section class="bg-magenta">MAGENTA</section>
  <section class="bg-yellow">YELLOW</section>
  <section class="bg-key">BLACK</section>
  <section class="bg-red">RED</section>
  <section class="bg-blue">BLUE</section>
  <section class="bg-green">GREEN</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks @com.on.ist, didn't see `both` option, yeah just tested it and you're right it behaves kind of weird, always likes to snap you back to original point if you don't scroll further enough, I tried `scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;` and it behaves like my original examples. But it is weird how `both` almost solves the problem but causes other unwanted behaviour. Thanks tho for checking this out for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had to use jQuery in the end to do a little hack to set HTML css `scroll-snap-type` value to `initial`...

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.bg-key').offset().top) {
    $('html').addClass('no-scroll-snap');
  } else {
    $('html').removeClass('no-scroll-snap');
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html.no-scroll-snap {
  scroll-snap-type: initial;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  color: white;
}

.bg-cyan {
  background: cyan;
}

.bg-magenta {
  background: magenta;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.bg-key {
  background: black;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main>
  <section class="bg-cyan">CYAN</section>
  <section class="bg-magenta">MAGENTA</section>
  <section class="bg-yellow">YELLOW</section>
  <section class="bg-key">BLACK</section>
  <section class="bg-red">RED</section>
  <section class="bg-blue">BLUE</section>
  <section class="bg-green">GREEN</section>
</main>
```